# Trying to debug memory leaks using Visual Studio 2008 Heap Debugger

Tags: c++, memory, macros, memory-leaks

We're trying to track down memory leaks in our Visual Studio C++ application. The application is unmanaged. I've been trying to use the VS Heap Debugger, to display file locations of leaked memory.

I've been trying to use the techniques explained here (see: "What is the effect of using '_CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC' on the C++ 'new' and 'delete' operators?"):

http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?312742-Visual-C-Debugging-How-to-manage-memory-leaks

and here (see: "How to make it work vol. 2"):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5ewb1h3%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

I've defined the following macro:

```
#ifdef CRT_DEBUGHEAP_ENABLE
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <crtdbg.h>
    #define DEBUG_NEW new(_NORMAL_BLOCK, __FILE__, __LINE__)
    #define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif
```

The problem is that we using the Microsoft xtree VS code, which includes the following:

```
_Nodeptr _Buynode(_Nodeptr _Larg, _Nodeptr _Parg,
                  _Nodeptr _Rarg, const value_type& _Val, char _Carg)
{   // allocate a node with pointers, value, and color
    _Nodeptr _Wherenode = this->_Alnod.allocate(1);
    _TRY_BEGIN
        new (_Wherenode) _Node(_Larg, _Parg, _Rarg, _Val, _Carg);
    _CATCH_ALL
    this->_Alnod.deallocate(_Wherenode, 1);
    _RERAISE;
    _CATCH_END
    return (_Wherenode);
}
```

The new statement allocates the memory at the specific location _Wherenode, and the macro fails:

```
error C2061: syntax error : identifier '_Wherenode'
```

I've tried multiple variadic macro definitions, but these also fail.

Can anyone help?

Comment: There's no decent way to do this.  Nor should you, the STL code doesn't have a leak and you don't want to edit it to fix a leak.  Just #include the CRT headers before the macro.  Asked many times before btw, review the google hits for "crtdbg placement new".

Comment: @ Hans: Thanks. The leak problems are in our code, not Microsoft's. I never realised that this version of new is "placement new". I've Googled for this and found out that it can't easily be solved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12815261/overriding-new-with-debug-version-without-damaging-placement-new. As you indicated, the only way to solve it is by rearranging the include order of #include files in the source code, and redefining new after all "placement new" declarations have been seen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The macro version of `new` prevents you from using placement new. The preprocessor expands the expression to the following

```
new(_NORMAL_BLOCK, __FILE__, __LINE__)(_Wherenode)
```

To work around this you need to undefine the macro before you include any header file that uses placement new.

```
#undef new
#include <xtree>
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#include <map>
```

Or a slightly safer way

```
#pragma push_macro("new")
#undef new
#include <xtree>
#pragma pop_macro("new")
#include <map>
```

Comment: @ Captain Oblivious: Thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately, it doesn't work because it's located in VS code, the file is "Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VS\include\xtree".

Comment: Noted as correct answer, since the placement version of new can't be used in a macro.